# How can I setup Ubuntu (and my home network router settings) so I can SSH to Linux console window?

Tags: networking, ssh, console, putty

I installed Ubuntu version 11 not too long ago.  I now have that computer running on my home network and it has it's own internal IP address on my home network behind a LinkSys Router.  How can I configure that Linux machine and my network settings so that I can SSH (using an emulator like Putty or Reflection) into that machine?

I'd rather not use VNC just to get access to its console Window.

====================

## Update 4/20/2012 @ 3:16pm

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping 192.168.1.103

Pinging 192.168.1.103 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.103: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.103: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.103: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.103: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.103:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 2ms, Average = 1ms

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: Use a key pair to log on from the Internet, do not allow passwords! I have too little time on my hands right now to give a complete answer, but please take my advise on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the `openssh-server` package.

If you want your machine to accessible from the outside world, you'll want to forward a port - the destination is port 22 on your computer; the source port can be anything.

If you only want it to be accessible on your home network, DON'T forward the port.

I'd also set up [SSH keys](http://www.paulkeck.com/ssh/), and possibly turn off password logins altogether.

You may also wish to install fail2ban or some other sort of access-control system (fail2ban checks for repeated failed logins & bans the IP with firewall rules.)

Comment: I am now forwarding 192.168.1.103 (Ubuntu machine) in my port forwarding section of my LinkSys Router on port 22.  When I try to Putty via SSH to that IP address, I get an error that says "Network error: Connection refused"

Comment: I'm able to ping that machine now, but Putty still won't connect (see update @ 3:16pm in question)

Comment: Dumb question - did you install openssh-server? It's not installed on the desktop distribution by default.

Comment: That is an excellent question for me (a person who has 0 networking experience).  Thanks for asking.  :-) +1

Comment: For those reading, it is not required to setup port forwarding on your router.  I wouldn't recommend doing so because the outside world can access your linux box then.

Comment: I had assumed OP *wanted* to access from outside world. I'll modify my answer.